# default route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I want users to be redirected to a maintenance page as soon as they enter my website, previously I achieved this with this route

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

however, for some reason now that route is not recognized, they enter in my homepage and I want them to be redirected to a route that shows a maintenance page when they enter, this is the htaccess code that is located at the root of the project

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.saludvitale.com/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /public/css/$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /public/js/$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ /public/img/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /public/images/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ /public/users/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^banner/(.*)$ /public/banner/$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ /public/uploads/$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*)$ /public/plugins/$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^chat-images/(.*)$ /public/chat-images/$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*)$ /public/fonts/$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^favicon.ico /public/favicon.ico [L]
        RewriteRule ^robots.txt /public/robots.txt [L]

    # Go ahead and process files.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I do not know much about htaccess, I do not know if the problem is causing the file, what could I do?

Comment: Define "not recognized". What happens?

Comment: hi ceejay, they are redirected to the homepage

Comment: I want them to be redirected to a route that shows a maintenance page when they enter

Comment: Why not use `php artisan down` for that? Exactly what it's for.

Comment: How would that do if my project is on a server?

Comment: SSH into the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> want users to be redirected to a maintenance page as soon as they enter my website

Laravel features `mainteance mode` for such purpose:

> When your application is in maintenance mode, a custom view will be
>   displayed for all requests into your application. This makes it easy
>   to "disable" your application while it is updating or when you are
>   performing maintenance.

No changes needed to be made to your code nor any other trickery, just enable that mode and voila.

See more here about mainteance mode: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#maintenance-mode

Comment: How would that do if my project is on a server?

Comment: how does it matter? it's part of framework, so once enabled it will just work be it on server or your local dev machine. it's just middleware that is by default enabled.